# System.Net vs. System.Web. What is the difference?

Tags: .net

One of the things I've noticed, but have never formally asked until now:  What is the difference between the classes in the System.Net namespace and the System.Web namespace?  Why do they both exist?  They seem to have different implementations of the same classes/concepts (Cookie, Mail, HttpWebRequest, for example).  Are they designed to be used for slightly different purposes?  Or is one a legacy namespace?

Comment: [**WEB**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145018(v=vs.110).aspx) <=> [**NET**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

It follows the natural segregation between client and server apps.  System.Web is (almost) exclusively used by .NET apps that implement a server.  Like an ASP.NET app.  It is notable for being missing in the Client framework profile.  System.Net contains classes useful to a client app.